# is it possible `cat` files role in ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible `cat` files role in ansible? my `defaults/main.yml` is :

```
---
srv1: webserver
srv2: db
srv3: dns
```

I want `cat` `defaults/main.yml` and `register` in a variable.

Comment: By register, do you mean to register the file contents as ansible variables or just the file as it is?

Comment: register the file contents as ansible variables

Comment: You could use the command module with the options `once: true` and `delegate_to: localhost`, so that the `cat` command is only executed once on the host running Ansible (where the file is probably located?). But these variables seem to be more suited to be put in the `host_vars` directory or to be turned into groups with the respective servers in them? What exactly do you want to do with the variables afterwards?

Comment: `Lookup` function is for you...

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you are looking for(in terms of `cat`) but if you want to include the variables in the playbook you can use `include_vars`:

```
- name: get me some vars
  include_vars:
    file: your_file.yml
    name: your_var
```

this will make your variables accessible at `your_var` (`your_var['srv1']` will be `webserver`)

According to the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_vars_module.html), if you miss the `name` parameter the variables will be included at top level scope.